# Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command

Tags: bash, replace, scripting, ironpython

What's the simplest way to do a find and replace for a given input string, say `abc`, and replace with another string, say `XYZ` in file `/tmp/file.txt`?

I am writing an app and using IronPython to execute commands through SSH — but I don't know Unix that well and don't know what to look for.

I have heard that Bash, apart from being a command line interface, can be a very powerful scripting language. If this is true, I assume you can perform actions like these.

Can I do it with Bash, and what's the simplest (one line) script to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1315, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `sed` (or Perl):

```bash
sed -i -e 's/abc/XYZ/g' /tmp/file.txt
```

which will invoke `sed` to do an in-place edit due to the `-i` option.  The `/g` flag for `sed`'s `s` command says to replace globally, i.e. do not substitute only the first occurrence on each input line. This can be called from Bash.

(The `-i` option is not standard. On BSD-based platforms, including MacOS, you need an explicit option argument `-i ''`.)

If you really really want to use just Bash, then the following can work:

```bash
while IFS='' read -r a; do
    echo "${a//abc/XYZ}"
done < /tmp/file.txt > /tmp/file.txt.t
mv /tmp/file.txt{.t,}
```

This loops over each line, doing a substitution, and writing to a temporary file (don't want to clobber the input).  The `mv` at the end just moves the temporary file to the original name. (For robustness and security, the temporary file name should not be static or predictable, but let's not go there.)

This uses a Bash-only [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to perform a replacement on the variable's value.

Comment: Except that invoking mv is pretty much as 'non Bash' as using sed. I nearly said the same of echo, but it's a shell builtin.

Comment: The -i argument for sed doesn't exist for Solaris (and I would think some other implementations) however, so keep that in mind. Just spent several minutes figuring that out...

Comment: Note to self: about regular expression of `sed`: 
`s/..../..../ - Substitute` and 
`/g - Global`

Comment: Ps: For me, this variant is 1/3 faster: `for a in \`cat hosts.txt\` ; do echo ${a//abc/XYZ} ; done  > hosts.txt.t`)

Comment: Note for Mac users who get an `invalid command code C` error...  For in-place replacements, BSD `sed` requires a file extension after the `-i` flag because it saves a backup file with the given extension.  For example: `sed -i '.bak' 's/find/replace/' /file.txt`  You can skip the backup by using an empty string like so: `sed -i '' 's/find/replace/' /file.txt`

Comment: Tip: If you want case insensitive repalce use `s/abc/XYZ/gi`

Comment: Anyway to disable the `RegEx` functionality and use them as only strings (Replace only the whole word)?

Comment: @Royi I'm not sure if I understood your question, as regex can replace whole words only. Simply type a word between / / slash characters. You must escape some characters with backslash, such as $, *, ", ', \.

Comment: @Royi Some `sed` dialects ellow you to put word anchors `s/\bfoo\b/bar/` to only replace `foo` if it is surrounded by word boundaries. However, the Perlism `\b` is not standard. Some older regex englines support `s/\<foo\>/bar/`

Comment: @BorisD.Teoharov The `i` flag is nonstandard; but if your `sed` has it, cool. Perl should have this flag in every version but is itself nonstandard.

Answer (score 183):

File manipulation isn't normally done by Bash, but by programs invoked by Bash, e.g.:

```
perl -pi -e 's/abc/XYZ/g' /tmp/file.txt
```

The `-i` flag tells it to do an in-place replacement.

See `man perlrun` for more details, including how to take a backup of the original file.

Comment: The purist in me says you can't be sure Perl will be available on the system. But that's very seldom the case nowadays. Perhaps I'm showing my age.

Comment: Can you show a more complex example. Something like replacing "chdir /blah" with "chdir /blah2". I tried `perl -pi -e 's/chdir (?:\\/[\\w\\.\\-]+)+/chdir blah/g' text`, but I keep getting an error with Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(chdir)( )( <-- HERE ?:\\/ at -e line 1.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061491/2730528

Comment: Why use Perl in this case when it's only function is to wrap a language around sed?

Comment: @EdwinBuck some sed implementations don't support in-place editing.

Comment: `perl` [command options](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uperl.htm) explained

Answer (score 85):

This is an old post but for anyone wanting to use variables as @centurian said the single quotes mean nothing will be expanded.

A simple way to get variables in is to do string concatenation since this is done by juxtaposition in bash the following should work:

```
sed -i -e "s/$var1/$var2/g" /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: I use this in a file:`sed "s/\"$li\"/- [x]\"\${li:5}\"/" $dat` ang get sed unterminated `s' command

Comment: Problem solved, well, ... $li comes from a file line, so there is e.g. \n and the error is there. So either awk or another language like python comes.

Answer (score 77):

I was surprised when I stumbled over this...

There is a `replace` command which ships with the `"mysql-server"` package, so if you have installed it try it out:

```
# replace string abc to XYZ in files
replace "abc" "XYZ" -- file.txt file2.txt file3.txt

# or pipe an echo to replace
echo "abcdef" |replace "abc" "XYZ"
```

See `man replace` for more on this.

Comment: Two things are possible here:
a) `replace` is a useful independent tool and the MySQL folks should release it separately and depend on it
b) `replace` requires some bit of MySQL o_O
Either way, installing mysql-server to get replace would be the wrong thing to do :)

Comment: only works for mac? in my ubuntu I centos that command does not exist

Comment: That's because you don't have `mysql-server` package installed. As pointed by @rayro, `replace` is part of it.

Comment: "Warning: replace is deprecated and will be removed in a future version."

Comment: As of 2018, it is included in the MariaDB package for Ubuntu.

Comment: Not as powerful, but I have a simple "script" here that does the same in case downloading a MySQL or MariaDB is overkill: https://gist.github.com/neuro-sys/3bf00b6cf28a93e07e44

Comment: Be careful not to run the REPLACE command on Windows!  On Windows the REPLACE command is for a fast replication of files.  Not relevant to this discussion.

Answer (score 48):

Bash, like other shells, is just a tool for coordinating other commands. Typically you would try to use standard UNIX commands, but you can of course use Bash to invoke anything, including your own compiled programs, other shell scripts, Python and Perl scripts etc.

In this case, there are a couple of ways to do it.

If you want to read a file, and write it to another file, doing search/replace as you go, use sed:

```sh
    sed 's/abc/XYZ/g' <infile >outfile
```

If you want to edit the file in place (as if opening the file in an editor, editing it, then saving it) supply instructions to the line editor 'ex'

```sh
    echo "%s/abc/XYZ/g
    w
    q
    " | ex file
```

Example is like `vi` without the fullscreen mode. You can give it the same commands you would at `vi`'s `:` prompt.

Comment: @awattar Just do them one at a time in a `for` loop.

Comment: Is there an option to use it together with globbing as a one liner?

Comment: Not as far as I know. `for f in report*.txt; do echo "%s/abc/XYZ/g \n w \n q \n" | ex file; done` is clean and simple. Why put functionality into `ex` that the shell already has?

Comment: (Or, if your problem outgrows the shell, use Python/Perl/whatever)

Answer (score 37):

I found this thread among others and I agree it contains the most complete answers so I'm adding mine too:

1. `sed` and `ed` are so useful...by hand.
   Look at this code from @Johnny:

   ```
   sed -i -e 's/abc/XYZ/g' /tmp/file.txt
   ```
2. When my restriction is to use it in a shell script, no variable can be used inside in place of "abc" or "XYZ". The [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021) seems to agree with what I understand at least. So, I can't use:

   ```
   x='abc'
   y='XYZ'
   sed -i -e 's/$x/$y/g' /tmp/file.txt
   #or,
   sed -i -e "s/$x/$y/g" /tmp/file.txt
   ```

   but, what can we do? As, @Johnny said use a `while read...` but, unfortunately that's not the end of the story. The following worked well with me:

   ```
   #edit user's virtual domain
   result=
   #if nullglob is set then, unset it temporarily
   is_nullglob=$( shopt -s | egrep -i '*nullglob' )
   if [[ is_nullglob ]]; then
      shopt -u nullglob
   fi
   while IFS= read -r line; do
      line="${line//'<servername>'/$server}"
      line="${line//'<serveralias>'/$alias}"
      line="${line//'<user>'/$user}"
      line="${line//'<group>'/$group}"
      result="$result""$line"'\n'
   done < $tmp
   echo -e $result > $tmp
   #if nullglob was set then, re-enable it
   if [[ is_nullglob ]]; then
      shopt -s nullglob
   fi
   #move user's virtual domain to Apache 2 domain directory
   ......
   ```
3. As one can see if `nullglob` is set then, it behaves strangely when there is a string containing a `*` as in:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
   ```

   which becomes

   ```
   <VirtualHost ServerName www.example.com
   ```

   there is no ending angle bracket and Apache2 can't even load.
4. This kind of parsing should be slower than one-hit search and replace but, as you already saw, there are four variables for four different search patterns working out of one  parse cycle.

The most suitable solution I can think of with the given assumptions of the problem.

Comment: In your (2) -- you can do `sed -e "s/$x/$y/"`, and it will work. Not the double quotes. It can get seriously confusing if the strings in the variables themselves contain characters with special meaning. For example if x="/" or x="\". When you hit these issues, it probably means you should stop trying to use the shell for this job.

Answer (score 34):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/abc/XYZ/gi' /tmp/file.txt
```

You can use `find` and `sed` if you don't know your filename:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/abc/XYZ/gi' {} \;
```

Find and replace in all Python files:

```
find ./ -iname "*.py" -type f -exec sed -i 's/abc/XYZ/gi' {} \;
```

Comment: `-i` isn't "ignore case", it's `-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]` (edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied))

Answer (score 17):

Be careful if you replace URLs with "/" character.

An example of how to do it:

```
sed -i "s%http://domain.com%http://www.domain.com/folder/%g" "test.txt"
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2015/07/linux-reemplazar-texto-en-archivos-con-sed.html

Answer (score 14):

If the file you are working on is not so big, and temporarily storing it in a variable is no problem, then you can use Bash string substitution on the whole file at once - there's no need to go over it line by line:

```
file_contents=$(</tmp/file.txt)
echo "${file_contents//abc/XYZ}" > /tmp/file.txt
```

The whole file contents will be treated as one long string, including linebreaks.

XYZ can be a variable eg `$replacement`, and one advantage of not using sed here is that you need not be concerned that the search or replace string might contain the sed pattern delimiter character (usually, but not necessarily, /). A disadvantage is not being able to use regular expressions or any of sed's more sophisticated operations.

Comment: Any tips for using this with tab characters? For some reason my script doesn't find anything with tabs after changing from sed with lots of escaping to this method.

Comment: If you want to put a tab in the string you're replacing, you can do so with Bash's "dollared single quotes" syntax, so a tab is represented by $'\t', and you can do
 $ echo 'tab'$'\t''separated' > testfile;

$ file_contents=$(<testfile);

$ echo "${file_contents//$'\t'/TAB}";

tabTABseparated
`

Answer (score 13):

You may also use the `ed` command to do in-file search and replace:

```
# delete all lines matching foobar 
ed -s test.txt <<< $'g/foobar/d\nw'
```

See more in "[Editing files via scripts with `ed`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed?s[]=ed)".

Comment: This solution is independent from GNU/FreeBSD (Mac OSX) incompatibilities (unlike `sed -i <pattern> <filename>`). Very nice!

Answer (score 6):

To edit text in the file non-interactively, you need in-place text editor such as vim.

Here is simple example how to use it from the command line:

```
vim -esnc '%s/foo/bar/g|:wq' file.txt
```

This is equivalent to [@slim answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/525606/55075) of [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) editor which is basically the same thing.

Here are few `ex` practical examples.

Replacing text `foo` with `bar` in the file:

```
ex -s +%s/foo/bar/ge -cwq file.txt
```

Removing trailing whitespaces for multiple files:

```
ex +'bufdo!%s/\s\+$//e' -cxa *.txt
```

Troubleshooting (when terminal is stuck):

- Add `-V1` param to show verbose messages.
- Force quit by: `-cwq!`.

See also:

- [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467) at Vi SE

Comment: Wanted to do the replacements interactively. Hence tried "vim -esnc '%s/foo/bar/gc|:wq' file.txt". But the terminal is stuck now. How shall we make the replacements interactively without the bash shell behaving weirdly.

Comment: To debug, add `-V1`, to force quit, use `wq!`.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following shell command:

```
find ./  -type f -name "file*.txt" | xargs sed -i -e 's/abc/xyz/g'
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer to "how do I accidentally all the files in all subdirectories, too" but that does not seem to be what is asked here.

Comment: This syntax won't work for BSD version of `sed`, use `sed -i''` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use python within the bash script too. I didn't have much success with some of the top answers here, and found this to work without the need for loops:

```
#!/bin/bash
python
filetosearch = '/home/ubuntu/ip_table.txt'
texttoreplace = 'tcp443'
texttoinsert = 'udp1194'

s = open(filetosearch).read()
s = s.replace(texttoreplace, texttoinsert)
f = open(filetosearch, 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rpl` command; this is an optional third-party tool (source at https://github.com/rrthomas/rpl/).  For example, if you want to change a domain name in a whole PHP project:

```
rpl -ivRpd -x'.php' 'old.domain.name' 'new.domain.name' ./path_to_your_project_folder/
```

This is  not pure Bash of cause, but it's a very quick and useful.

Comment: This is easily done with standard tools as well. The `sed` solutions on this page show how to do it in one directory (though you need `sed -i` which is also nonstandard for most of them); just plug in into `find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec ... \;` to replace recursively in all `*.php` files in a directory tree.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to replace multiple text in a file using the `sed` command

```
sed -i 's#a/b/c#D/E#g;s#/x/y/z#D:/X#g;' filename
```

In the above command `s#a/b/c#D/E#g` I am replacing `a/b/c` with `D/E` and then after the `;` we are again doing the same thing with `x/y/z` and `D:/X`

Answer (score 1):

For MAC users in case you don't read the comments :)

As mentioned by @Austin, if you get the `Invalid command code` error

For the in-place replacements `BSD sed` requires a file extension after the `-i` flag to save to a backup file with given extension.

`sed -i '.bak' 's/find/replace' /file.txt`

You can use `''` empty string if you want to skip backup.

`sed -i '' 's/find/replace' /file.txt`

All merit to @Austin

Answer (score 1):

Open file using vim editor. In command mode

```
:%s/abc/xyz/g
```

This is the simplest

Comment: Dubious. The user then separately has to learn how to quit Vim.

Answer (score -1):

In case of doing changes in multiple files together we can do in a single line as:-

```
user_name='whoami'
for file in file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt; do sed -i -e 's/default_user/${user_name}/g' $file; done
```

Added if in case could be useful.

Comment: The loop does nothing useful; `sed` natively knows how to process multiple files. Also, you have a bug: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)