# How to insert a new line character after a fixed number of characters in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking for a bash or sed script (preferably a one-liner) with which I can insert a new line character after a fixed number of characters in huge text file.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command among many, many others

Comment: I disagree by the dupe comment here, Neil: this is not a simple search and replace like the question in your link..

Answer (score 65, accepted):

How about something like this? Change 20 is the number of characters before the newline, and temp.text is the file to replace in..

```
sed -e "s/.\{20\}/&\n/g" < temp.txt
```

Comment: Fails if the file contains a '~' character

Comment: This inserts a newline after *every* 20 characters (per line of the original). If the original contains no newlines and you want a newline after only the first 20 characters, leave out the "g" (global) at the end. If you want this and the original contains newlines, you'll have to use a different solution.

Comment: I had the same problem but in OSX it inserts an "n" rather than a line break? I checked other posts with the same problem but I could not understand how to fix it? Anyone please?

Comment: @JM88, Unix/Linux use the line-feed character (`\n`) for line breaks. Mac uses the carriage-return character for line breaks (`\r`), and Windows uses a combination of the two (`\r\n`) for line breaks. Change the command to `sed -e "s/.\{20\}/&\r/g" < temp.txt`, and you should get what you need. See also [this Stack-O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013034/does-windows-carriage-return-r-n-consist-of-two-characters-or-one-character) and [this blog](http://www.danielmiessler.com/study/crlf/) about it.

Comment: A lot of sed implementations limit the number of selected characters to 255. Prefer the Steven Penny's response.

Comment: Does not work on OSX with a file.containing a base64 encoded string.

Comment: I think the use of `fold` in is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Let N be a shell variable representing the count of characters after which you want a newline.  If you want to continue the count accross lines:

```
perl -0xff -pe 's/(.{'$N'})/$1\n/sg' input
```

If you want to restart the count for each line, omit the -0xff argument.

Answer (score 2):

Because I can't comment directly (to less reputations) a new hint to upper comments:

I prefer the **sed** command (exactly what I want) and also tested the Posix-Command **fold**. But there is a little difference between both commands for the original problem:
If you have a flat file with n*bytes records (without any linefeed characters) and use the **sed** command (with bytes as number (20 in the answer of @Kristian)) you got n lines if you count with **wc**. If you use the **fold** command you only got n-1 lines with **wc**!
This difference is sometimes important to know, if your input file doesn't contain any newline character, you got one after the last line with **sed** and got no one with **fold**

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you want to insert your newline after a number of characters with respect to the whole file, eg after the 30th character in the whole file

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ FS=""; ch=30}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        c+=1
        if (c==ch){
            print "" 
            c=0           
        }else{
            printf $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
```

if you mean insert at specific number of characters in each line eg after every 5th character

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ FS=""; ch=5}
{
    print substr($0,1,ch) "\n" substr($0,ch)
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Append an empty line after a line with exactly 42 characters

```
sed -ie '/^.\{42\}$/a\
' huge_text_file
```

Comment: I think sed is often is better without the `-i` flag when used on the command line as you won't accidentally overwrite your original file with unwanted output if you make a typo when writing your command. I feel the answer should at least warn people what `-i` does in case they are not familiar with sed and don't first check the flags they use.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaax | sed 's/./&\n/20'
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
x
```

Comment: literally only works for the first line (eg inserts newline after 20 chars and then quits). Not suitable for "a huge text file".