# BASH: Split MAC Address -> 000E0C7F6676 to 00:0E:0C:7F:66:76

Tags: macos, bash, string, split

Hy,

Can someone help me with splitting mac addresses from a log file? :-)

This:

```
000E0C7F6676
```

should be:

```
00:0E:0C:7F:66:76
```

Atm i split this with OpenOffice but with over 200 MAC Address' this is very boring and slow...

It would be nice if the solution is in bash. :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it just a list of mac addresses, or is there something else in the file?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187078/how-to-insert-a-new-line-character-after-a-fixed-number-of-characters-in-a-file

Comment: There are some other data in the file. It works now with a little "Workaround" and your snippet. Thank you all. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple sed script ought to do it.

```
sed -e 's/[0-9A-F]\{2\}/&:/g' -e 's/:$//' myFile
```

That'll take a list of mac addresses in `myFile`, one per line, and insert a ':' after every two hex-digits, and finally remove the last one.

Comment: @Peter; note that this is a fairly brain-damaged way of doing it, and will ONLY work in this particular case. It's only marginally better than `sed -e 's/../&:/g' -e 's/:$//' myFile`, which might actually be better as it's simpler.

Comment: Yeah i saw it. But it works and the snippet will just be used around 10 times in a year. So it's OK. No need for perfect solution in this case. Thank you for your answer and your comment. :-)

Comment: Might be worth noting that this only works on uppercase hex digits, if you want lower case as well you'd add `a-f` to the brackets right after the `A-Z` so you'd end up with something like `sed -e 's/[0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}/&:/g' -e 's/:$//' myFile`

Answer (score 6):

```
$ mac=000E0C7F6676
$ s=${mac:0:2}
$ for((i=1;i<${#mac};i+=2)); do s=$s:${mac:$i:2}; done
$ echo $s
00:00:E0:C7:F6:67:6
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to get this working: `${mac//??/??:/}`, that is, do you know how to get whatever got expanded in the substituted part?

Comment: +1 Wrap this in a `for mac in $(cat file-with-macs.txt); do { ... }` and it's a nice, pure bash solution for the OP's whole problem.

Comment: @Dan: No, it should be `while read -r line; do ...; done < file-with-macs.txt`. @roe: See my answer.

Comment: your loop should be `for((i=2;i<${#mac};i+=2))` Notice the mac address in your output is invalid/incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Pure Bash. This snippet

```
mac='000E0C7F6676'

array=()
for (( CNTR=0; CNTR<${#mac}; CNTR+=2 )); do
  array+=( ${mac:CNTR:2} )
done
IFS=':'
string="${array[*]}"
echo -e "$string"
```

prints

```
00:0E:0C:7F:66:76
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a='0123456789AB'
m=${a:0:2}:${a:2:2}:${a:4:2}:${a:6:2}:${a:8:2}:${a:10:2}
```

result:

```
01:23:45:67:89:AB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -lne 'print join ":", $1 =~ /(..)/g while /\b([\da-f]{12})\b/ig' file.log
00:0E:0C:7F:66:76
```

If you prefer to save it as a program, use

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -ln    
print join ":" => $1 =~ /(..)/g
  while /\b([\da-f]{12})\b/ig;
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./macs file.log 
00:0E:0C:7F:66:76
```

Answer (score 1):

imo, regular expressions are the wrong tool for a fixed width string.

`perl -alne 'print join(":",unpack("A2A2A2A2A2A2",$_))' filename`

Alternatively,

`gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 2 2 2 2 2' -v OFS=':' '{$1=$1;print }'`

That's a little funky with the assignment to change the behavior of print.  Might be more clear to just print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6

Comment: Beat me to it... knew gawk had to have ananswer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Requires Bash version >= 3.2

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..6}
do
    pattern+='([[:xdigit:]]{2})'
done

saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=':'
while read -r line
do
    [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]
    mac="${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}"
    echo "$mac"
done < macfile.txt > newfile.txt
IFS=$saveIFS
```

If your file contains other information besides MAC addresses that you want to preserve, you'll need to modify the regex and possibly move the `IFS` manipulation inside the loop.

Unfortunately, there's not an equivalent in Bash to `sed 's/../&:/'` using something like `${mac//??/??:/}`.

Comment: Thanks, that's too bad (I mean the `${mac//??/??:/}` part).