# url encoding returns unwanted characters

Tags: php

I am trying to encode a base url; the problem is I am getting unwanted characters at the end of each url. Can you help me debug my code in removing these characters?

```
<?php

$names = file('query-file.txt');
$baseUrl = 'whois.whoisxmlapi.com/';
foreach($names as $name) {
    $url = $baseUrl . urlencode($name);
    $record = rtrim($url);
    echo $record.'<br>';
}

?>
```

output

```
whois.whoisxmlapi.com/google.com%0D%0A
whois.whoisxmlapi.com/cnn.com%0D%0A
whois.whoisxmlapi.com/msn.com%0D%0A
whois.whoisxmlapi.com/hotmail.com%0D%0A
whois.whoisxmlapi.com/yahoo.com%0D%0A
whois.whoisxmlapi.com/gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Each line in your file ends with `"\r\n"` (hexadecimal values 0xD and 0xA), also known as [windows newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7013341/98057).

Use the [`FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) flag on the call to `file()`, which will simply exclude the newlines:

```
$names = file('query-file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Or use the [`rtrim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim) function on each line to get rid of the trailing whitespace, before encoding it:

```
$url = $baseUrl . urlencode(rtrim($name));
```

Answer (score 0):

you used encode that's why unwanted characters came. try urldecode instead of urlencode 
may be this one is helpful to you :-)