# Atom text editor adds "^M" to empty lines

Tags: git, atom-editor

Atom text editor adds this symbol to every empty line.

Any idea what and why?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

I'm on Ubuntu Linux and noticed the ^M (Carriage Return, Line Feed) during `git diff`.

Somehow CRLF was selected at the bottom of the status bar:

[image: CRLF in Atom status bar]

I simply clicked it and changed to LF:

[image: LF in Atom Status Bar]

It seems to be set on a file-by-file basis so will need to be changed for each problem file.

---

In my case somehow all the line endings had been changed so `git diff` was a sea of red.  I used the following to identify 'real' changes:

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol
```

However, `git commit` would still bury the 'real' changes in commit history so I:

1. ran `git stash save`
2. changed line endings in atom
3. ran `git commit -am "fix line endings"`
4. ran `git stash apply`

Now the line endings are gone and commits can be made on a precise diff.

Comment: O man! you made may day. I/m not sure why it change to CRLF but anyway. thanks for this.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Atom text editor under Windows?
Windows carriage return is `\r\n` while it is `\n` in Unix.
`^M` ( `0xD` or `\r` ) is the carriage return character in Windows.
I think, that file was previously saved under Unix ( and already have `\n` on each line), so Atom is adding `\r` as required by Windows.

For more information you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843561/5247040) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013034/does-windows-carriage-return-r-n-consist-of-two-characters-or-one-character)

Comment: Atom will show which line ending it is using at the bottom right of the status bar. See the plugin [documentation](https://github.com/atom/line-ending-selector). Changing it there will modify line endings for that file. In `Settings > Packages > line-ending-selector` you can set the default line ending for new files as well.

Comment: From @DavidUlrich's comment, i dig abit into the package.

From the above exercise, I found that the files in the repo i was working on were all CRLF. I concluded that since the project was previously done by another developer, most likely, bless him, he was using windows.

Answer (score 3):

Check your bottom of the editor which might have changed your file line endings.

Usually it is LF for Unix

[image]

and CRLF for windows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most of the solutions I've found online involve using sed, vi, or emacs. I found a solution that works directly within Atom (and probably any text editor), no command line needed.

Select all of the returns, or get a selector at the beginning of every line then delete and hit return. It might take a second, but it will get rid of all of the ^M characters.

This will likely screw up your indenting, but you can auto-indent. This might not be efficient if you have multiple files you need to do this with, but it's a quick and dirty solution for just one file.