# Input file not displaying properly because of ¤ ¬ (currency symbol)

Tags: c++, xcode, ifstream

So I've been using this input file and beating myself up because no matter what I did, it would not display properly for me. I did figure out why it was happening but I want to know what the **¤** (Currency symbol) next to the EOL (End of line) **¬** means, and why it isn't easy to add or remove them (**¤**). I have never came across this problem or seen anything posted about it, primarly because I don't know what the **¤** really is, if I had to take a guess I'd say it is some sort of linebreak or newline. Maybe this is one of those nice Apple bugs in xCode.

**Update 3**

Input function:

```
while (!mDataFile.eof())
{
    MLSInfo temp;
    //mDataFile >> temp.mlsId;
    mDataFile >> temp.mlsId;
    mDataFile >> temp.salePrice;

    mDataFile.ignore();
    getline(mDataFile, temp.address);

    if (!mDataFile.eof()){
        list.listInsertEnd(temp);
    }
}
```

Output function:

```
DListNode* tempPtr = list.getHead();
while (tempPtr != nullptr) {
    MLSInfo temp = tempPtr->dataVal ;
    cout << temp.mlsId << " " << temp.salePrice << " " << temp.address << "";
    tempPtr = tempPtr->nextNodePtr;
}
```

**Update 2:**

Download link of broken file.
https://ufile.io/jzyxx

**Update 1:**

STRING:

```
00111 75000.00 123 Main Street¤¬
```

HEX:

```
30 30 31 31 31 20 37 35 30 30 30 2e 30 30 20 31 
32 33 20 4d 61 69 6e 20 53 74 72 65 65 74 0d 0a
```

UNICODE CODE FOR ¤:

```
U+00A4
```

[image]

What the output looked like

[image]

To fix the problem I just removed all the **¤**'s by retyping the input file.

[image]

Comment: Open a hex editor and actually get the byte values for those characters.  Posting pictures of the character is not going to be good enough.

Comment: it is 0d , Unicode code is U+00A4. See update

Comment: It looks like Xcode is showing you whitespace characters. When you copy and paste here, those characters should just be whitespace, not the actual Unicode Apple's using to display them...is that hexdump of the actual file? Or of the text you posted where you actually used Unicode ¤?

Comment: I hexed dumped the whole file, you can check for yourself though. Download link of broken file. https://ufile.io/jzyxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like those light gray Unicode characters are Xcode's way of displaying whitespace characters. The dots are spaces and the arrows are newlines, so I'd guess your currency symbols are carriage returns.

Looking at your hexdump, we see character `0x0d`. Comparing with an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) confirms that it is indeed a carriage return.

Since the default delimiter for `getline` is a newline*, this carriage return is going straight into your string! This will affect things when you then try to output that string later. (without seeing your code, it's hard to say why it's printing the way it is)

How these could've gotten into your file is a mystery without more information (was the file on a windows machine at some point?), but simply removing them from the file should be enough to solve your problems.

---

<sup>*Realized I'm assuming the use of `getline` here because if you were using `cin` with the `>>` operator, it would stop at **any** whitespace, including carriage returns.</sup>

Comment: The file was most likely created on windows, than uploaded to blackboard as it is a school project, than downloaded by me. This is a project that involves pointers, doubly linked lists. My output was `cout << temp.mlsId << " " << temp.salePrice << " " <<  temp.address << "";` Note that there isn't an endl.

Comment: @Greg432 see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013034/does-windows-carriage-return-r-n-consist-of-two-characters-or-one-character). Windows by default uses those pesky things on every line, which would explain how they got there. How do you pull those values from the line? Do you use a stringstream with the `>>` operator?

Comment: @Greg432 be careful of posting your full code (especially if it's a school assignment). Can you just give the part where you read from the file and the part where you output?

Comment: @Greg432 I'm taking a look at your code and I have no idea how that's printing on separate lines at all. The `getline` should be eating the newline character, leaving a trailing carriage return that'll reset the cursor to the beginning of the line. I made a mock file to test and I see what I would expect--only one the last line being output (since it each line writes on the same line every time). Are you sure you're not putting a newline in there somewhere?