# How to avoid break line symbol when merging two files?

Tags: linux, cat

```
- tell me about yourself^M
  20 - bye for now
  21 - tell me about you^M
  22 - catch you later
  23 - about yourself^M
```

I use the following command to merge two text files:

```
cat 1.txt >> 2.txt
```

But the merged file introduced lots of ^M. How to void that? I am working on Mac Pro.

Comment: maybe this file come from a windows macchine

Comment: Before I merged, the two files don't contain this symbol. After merging, this symbol is introduced.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013034/does-windows-carriage-return-r-n-consist-of-two-characters-or-one-character

Comment: Please provide `xxd -g 1 < 1.txt` and `xxd -g 1 < 2.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ^M is a carriage return character, octal 015.  Delete it with `tr`'

```
cat 1.txt | tr -d '\015' >> 2.txt
```