# Pandas read_fwf use in file with contiguous bytes and no line terminators

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with fixed-width records that are not separated by newlines or any other terminator; the file is just a contiguous byte stream.  Pandas read_fwf correctly reads the first record then stops. Is there a way to force read_fwf to continue reading all records to the end of file?  I did not see any arg for this in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a good pandas solution. You might want to try pre-processing your input file using `fold`, `awk`, `sed`, etc. to the number of characters or bytes that should exist on each line. Check out this discussion: [How to insert a new line character after a fixed number of characters in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187078/how-to-insert-a-new-line-character-after-a-fixed-number-of-characters-in-a-file)