# Sed replace line "Linux Directory " with new Directory structure

Tags: regex, linux, sed

So not sure, but i tried the following and it didn't work.
What string can i use to replace a directory string in `sed`?

```
sed 's"/usr/lib64/$id""/home/user1/$id"/g' 1.php > 1_new.php
```

Comment: Related: [How to replace a path with another path in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12061410/1258041) and [Replace a string in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script).

Answer (score 0):

Because your strings have slashes in them, it is convenient to use a different separator in the substitution expression.  Here, I use `|` as the separator.  If, for simplicity, we ignore the double-quotes inside your regular expression, we could use:

```
sed "s|/usr/lib64/$id|/home/user1/$id|g" 1.php > 1_new.php
```

If we include the double-quotes, then quoting because a bit more complex:

```
sed 's|"/usr/lib64/'"$id"'"|"/home/user1/'"$id"'"|g' 1.php > 1_new.php
```

I assume that you intend for `$id` to be replaced by the value of the shell variable `id`.  If so, it is important in both cases that the expression `$id` not be inside single-quotes as they inhibit variable expansion.

#### Discussion of Quoting

The quoting in the second case may look ugly.  To help explain, I will add some spaces to separate the sections of the string:

```
sed 's|"/usr/lib64/' "$id" '"|"/home/user1/' "$id" '"|g' # Don't use this form.
```

From the above, we can see that the `sed` command is made up of a single-quoted string, `'s|"/usr/lib64/'` followed by a double-quoted string, `"$id"`, followed by a single-quoted string, `'"|"/home/user1/'`, followed by a double-quoted string, `"$id"`, followed by a single-quoted string, `'"|g'`.  Because everything is in single-quotes except that which we explicitly want the shell to expand, this is generally the approach that is safest against surprises.

#### Alternate Quoting Style

The following quoting style may seem simpler:

```
sed "s|\"/usr/lib64/$id\"|\"/home/user1/$id\"|g" 1.php > 1_new.php
```

In the above, the `sed` command is all one double-quoted string.  Double-quotes can be included within double-quoted strings by escaping them as `\"`.  This style is fine as long as you are confident that you know that the shell won't expand anything except what you want expanded.