# Change the string which has multiple '/' delimiters

Tags: string, unix, sed

I have a string like `string1="app/local/home/usr/data/"` that I want to replace with `string2="app2/local/home/blablabla"`. How can I replace the `string1` with `string2`? I tried using `sed` which did not work.

Comment: Take note that: 1) the separator for the `s` ed command is *not* `/`, it is more or less arbitrary and 2) the separator can be escaped with `\\`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a path with another path in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061410/how-to-replace-a-path-with-another-path-in-sed)

Answer (score 0):

This script would give you the best solution , I think..

```
#!/bin/sh
string1="app/local/home/usr/data/";

text=$(dirname $(dirname $string1));
echo $text|sed "s/app/app2/"|
 sed -e "s/(.*\)/\1\/blahblah/"
```

This gives output after executing the script.sh

```
app2/local/home/blahblah
```