# find and replace text in multiple files

Tags: regex, bash, sed, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command)

I've been told to change all the title tags in a website.

Because the title tag it's in all the pages of the website (more than 30) and it's static, I need to go file by file in order to replace this title with the new one.

So I was wondering if someone knows a script that can achieve this without having to do it manually in a one by one basis.

Example:

```
/var/www/websitename/
```

Inside this path, there is multiple .html files which I have to change the title from:

```
 <title>Old title</title>
```

To:

```
 <title>New title</title>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `sed` fix your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one (after a backup of the folder, because here `sed` works in-place).

```
find /var/www/websitename/ -name '*.html' -exec sed -i.bak 's/.title.Old title..title./<title>New title<\/title>/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pi -e 's/\<title\>Old title\<\/title\>/\<title\>New title\<\/title\>/g' *.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use notepad++ as well. Open all files (just mark them and drag on notepad++ or drag the whole folder), press ctrl+f, switch to second tab("replace" or something like this - i'm not using english version), type your text(you can use regexp as well - see options) and click "replace in all opened files"(or someting like this). It's not as powewrfull solution as using scripts, but it's easier and often it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

old_title="<title>Old title<\/title>"
new_title="<title>New title<\/title>"

for file in $(find . -name "*.html");
do
    `sed -i "s/${old_title}/${new_title}/g" ${file}`
done
```