# Shell Script: Overwrite entire line in a text file if a partial match is found

Tags: shell, sed, awk

A similar question like this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command), but I would like something slightly different.  My issue is this, if my file `foobar.txt` looks like this:

```
ABCdefg
hijklmn
```

How can I search for the `ABC` on each line of the file, and if "`ABC`" is found, that entire line needs to be replaced to `AAAAAAA`.  So the final output of the file would be:

```
AAAAAAA
hijklmn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this sed line:

```
sed '/ABC/s/.*/AAAAAAA/' file
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "ABCdefg
hijklmn
xxABC"|sed '/ABC/s/.*/AAAAAAA/'
AAAAAAA
hijklmn
AAAAAAA
```

or awk one-liner:

```
awk '/ABC/{$0="AAAAAAA"}7' file
```

test omitted.

Comment: @cnicutar non-zero number, by default awk will do `print $0`

Comment: I seem to have missed something.  My actual file I wanted parsed is here: http://pastebin.com/CRmfLWf8.  While my bash file is here: http://pastebin.com/5mYMp2Jr.  The file remains unchanged after I run my script file

Comment: @JohnCrawford if you want to change the file in place, with (gnu)sed you need `sed -i '...' file`, with awk (if your awk < gnu awk 4.1.0): `awk '...' /path/to/file > /tmp/tmpfile && mv /tmp/tmpfile /path/to/file`

Comment: For completeness sake, maybe also mention `sed '/ABC/c\ AAAAAAA'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/ABC/s/./A/g' file
```