# Swap value in column 1

Tags: shell, unix, bioinformatics

I have a file that looks like this:

```
CHROM POS ID REF ALT
22 345 567 A G
22 454 666 T G
23 454 555 C C
23 565 777 G G
```

And I want to change it to:

```
CHROM POS ID REF ALT
22 345 567 A G
22 454 666 T G
X 454 555 C C
X 565 777 G G
```

i.e. In column 1, I want to swap 23 with X. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GNU `sed` you could do like this:

```
sed -e 's/^23\>/X/' file.txt
```

Or using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^23\b/X/' file.txt
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk '{ if ($1 == 23) sub("23", "X"); print }' file.txt
```

If you want to update the file after the replacement, then you can use any of these commands:

```
sed -i -e 's/^23\>/X/' file.txt
perl -pi -e 's/^23\b/X/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to any scripting languages? a perl or python script to replace a line start followed by 23 with a line start followed by X would be pretty simple.

see this answer: [Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command)

so something like...

```
perl -pi -e 's/^23\s/X /g' /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: why do you match with `\n` instead of `^` (beginning of line)?

Comment: good catch. that would be the correct method. My original answer would miss items on line one.

Comment: also, are you sure about sub string `X\s`? it won't re-add the space between 23 and the 454 or whatever