# Replacing string in text file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I'm trying to replace a string in a file using a script in linux.

After reading this post : 
[Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command)

I used the following line

```
perl -pi -e "s/myparam/$MY_VAR/g" /res/raw/configuration.xml
```

But the problem is that `MY_VAR`contains a url (something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), which contains `/` and it doesn't replaces the string at all.

I assume i don't need to write a script that does find and replace to all the `/` and there is a simple way to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pi -e 's/myparam/$ENV{MY_VAR}/g' /res/raw/configuration.xml
```

or put `$MY_VAR` on command line instead of interpolating it into perl one liner,

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{$s = shift} s/myparam/$s/g' $MY_VAR /res/raw/configuration.xml
```

Comment: `$ENV{MY_VAR}` would be the natural way to use a shell variable.

Comment: @TLP tnx for comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed with alternate delimiter:

```
sed -i.bak "s~myparam~$MY_VAR~g" /res/raw/configuration.xml
```

`Perl` also allows same so use:

```
perl -pi -e "s~myparam~$MY_VAR~g" /res/raw/configuration.xml
```

Comment: You can also use an alternate delimiter in Perl.

Comment: Yes right, I was just verifying it first before adding that to answer. Thanks.