# Set python path using bash Script?

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-3.5

I have a bash script which performs a certain set of functions and uses Python 3.5 for running commands within itself. I can store the output of

```
 which python
```

in a variable but I need to set it in the file named .bash_profile so that I can call

```
python3.5 some_command
```

from within the bash script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `x="which python"` and then `eval $x`.

See here: [How to store a command in a variable in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-linux)

If you want to store it in a file, you can always call `which python >> outfile` and then `cat outfile` to read the contents back

Or you can use `sed` or `awk` to replace some text in a config file like `.bash_profile` or whatever. See [Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command).

So if there was a placeholder location called `PythonLocation` in .bash_profile, you could do

```
x="which python"
eval $x
sed -i -e 's/PythonLocation/$x/g' .bash_profile
```