# How to populate git commit date in to java file

Tags: java, git, gitlab

I was working on a task in which multiple java files having date variable.

Before commit:
private String DATE="$DATE$"

In which once i committed those changes into GIT repo, is there any possible way to do git hook that will populate the committed date automatically into the java files.

After commit: (it should auto populate the committed date)
private String DATE="$DATE: 2019-10-05 13:10:45 $"

Any help, will be really appreciated.

Comment: See [git-commit-id maven plugin](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/blob/master/maven/docs/using-the-plugin.md).

Comment: @DavidConrad- it was ant based

Comment: In case you don't have maven on your project, you should look into [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/525612/5521670) bash command in combination with [date](https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-date-format-options-examples/).

Comment: In that case, I don't know.