# Find and replace match after string in different file from bash script - not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a string stored in a variable called newOccupation in file2.sh. When I run file2.sh, I would like it to replace whatever is after the word "occupation=" with the string stored in newOccupation.

So in this case, after running the script, occupation="Cashier" should be changed to occupation="Teacher"

I tried to replicate something from a very similar thread here [Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command)
but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if it's due to formatting issues from trying to insert a variable instead of a string in the executed command.

file1.txt

```
name="Bobby"
age="23"
occupation="Cashier"
favoriteColor="Red"
```

file2.sh

```
newOccupation="Teacher"
sed -i -e 's/[occupation=]+/"'${newOccupation}'"/g' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your file2.sh:

```
newOccupation="Teacher"
sed -i "s/occupation=\".*\"/occupation=\"${newOccupation}\"/" file1.txt
```